# How to add dependencies to play framework using SBT

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm trying to add the following dependencies into my new `play-framework` project

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4
```

so I add the following into `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.json-lib" % "json-lib" % "2.4"
```

however, when I try to run the application (`./activator run`) I get the following error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /****/project
[info] Set current project to *** (in build file:/***/)
[info] Updating {file:/****/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /***/.ivy2/local/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/jars/json-lib.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /****/activator/repository/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/jars/json-lib.jar
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/jars/json-lib.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
...
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed Sep 9, 2016 1:30:47 PM
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT NOTE:**

just realised the `Download ( JAR )` in `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4` doesn't work either,

could it be an issue with repository itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

the problem was I needed to add classifier to the line:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.json-lib" % "json-lib" % "2.4" classifier "jdk15"
```

for more information check out this link, it explain in more details:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html